# Deja Dup resolves host name incorrectly, adds ISP hostname

Tags: networking, deja-dup, duplicity

**PROBLEM:**
I backup to an SSH server via Deja Dup. Recently I am recieving warnings that: my backups are for a computer called `my_actual_hostname` but the current computer is `my_hostname.hawaii.rr.com`.

**My questions are:**
How is Deja Dup resolving my hostname? I have my hostname in `/etc/hostname`. Python resolves the correct hostname with `socket.getfqdn()`.

Where should I look to troubleshoot? I have already reset my router to factory default.

What could cause Deja Dup, or duplicity, to tack on my ISPs name to my computer name?

Answer (score 3):

I had changed my hostname in `/etc/hostname` but I forgot to change it in `/etc/hosts`. Edit hosts file so that it matches hostname and duplicity is all better.