# Deja Dup Device Name Issue

Tags: deja-dup, hostname, duplicity

My Linux desktop is 4 years old. I originally named it "foo", but 2ish years ago renamed it "bar". I turned on backups for the first time today using Deja Dup, and it used the old computer/hostname from 4 years ago, "foo", as opposed to the current name "bar". I cannot figure out where the old hostname is coming from. I've verified the name is correct in the following locations:

- `/etc/hosts`
- `/etc/hostname`
- `hostname`
- `hostnamectl`
- Settings > About > Device Name
- `python -c 'import socket; print socket.getfqdn()'`
- `uname -n`

I'm at a loss. I'm not sure where the old hostname would still be stored, and how Deja Dup is attempting to discern the computer name for the backup path. Any ideas?!

Comment: Guess - delete the cache in /home/[userid]/.cache/deja-dup/ and retry.

Comment: Didn't work - good idea though!

Comment: Sorry - this is a strange one.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with Deja Dup using my public IPv6 address. I solved it by changing `/etc/hosts` to this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   computerName
::1         localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

The backups are now getting named properly to `computerName` and no longer changing.

Related links:
[Backup stops because of claim 'Computer name changed', which is it not true](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187679/backup-stops-because-of-claim-computer-name-changed-which-is-it-not-true)
[Deja Dup resolves host name incorrectly, adds ISP hostname](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264529/deja-dup-resolves-host-name-incorrectly-adds-isp-hostname)